# wp_enqueue_scripts in a plugin's class

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui

I'm trying to enqueue jQuery UI in a plugin under a class method. I have this so far:

```
class AV_Slider {

function slider_load_js(){
        wp_register_script('jquery-ui-core', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script('av_slider_js', AV_SLIDER_BASE_URL . 'includes/js/av_slider.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}


function __construct(){
    $this->hooks();
}
function hooks(){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slider_load_js');
}
```

And I get this error on the page:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'slider_load_js' not found or invalid function name

I'm not sure how __construct() works other than that it creates a new Simple XML object. I also tried adding the action `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slider_load_js');` after the function but this caused an error as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - I'm not sure why you are registering `jquery-ui-core`. WordPress has already registered jQuery UI scripts (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress)). You should use the shipped jquery and jquery-ui scripts rather than registering your own.

As for the error - the second argument `add_action` (and `apply_filter` for that matter) is a [callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). To have a class method as a callback, you need to specify the class. In your case, using `$this`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'slider_load_js'));
```

Comment: Also you first use of `wp_enqueue_script` is incorrect, and would be, in any case, unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks got it. Do you use the __construct() method each time you need to add actions/filters in a class?

Comment: ? - you would generally construct the class once and then all your actions/filers are added then...